# Bootstrap col-sm making content disappear

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I add col-sm-* to any of my left or right columns the content completely disappears. With developer tools it looks like the areas are where they are suppose to be, but there isn't any content.

The elements in question are left-column and right-column divs.
Here is the page: http://www.silverfishdevelopment.com/clients/maafs

I'm just drawing a blank on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can see "Right" in your right column. Are you saying that you can't see that on your page?

Comment: I can see them...content in the left col, and 'RIGHT' in the right col...

Comment: If you emulate say a Nexus 7 v2 they disappear. I'm trying to get the site to be responsive.

Comment: I am assuming it is heading down to the xs breakpoint. If so, you also need to add a `col-xs-*` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your markup, you have it abit wrong.

.row is meant to be a child of .container / .container-fluid.

So instead of:

```
<div id="bottomSection" class="container-fluid row">
...
</div>
```

make it

```
<div id="bottomSection" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
         ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
         ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also you don't need to do .col-md-8 if your sm column is also going to also have  8 grids, you can use just .col-sm-8 and on md screens it will also take that width.

Comment: I made the HTML changes you suggested, but it didn't change anything. I removed .row completely and still nothing. When I inspect, it highlights the elements saying they are in the right place, but still no content.

Comment: @Gamegoofs2 your html still doesn't have .row as a child of .container-fluid

Comment: Adding .row doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Gamegoofs2 .row is used to wrap a single row (by default is 12 columns), you have a column with .col-sm-8, .col-sm-4 & .col-md-12, this is 24 rows.

.row should only wrap those 12 rows as that is how many grids bootstrap by default has.

Your .col-md-12 should have it's own .row parent