# bootstrap col-xs makes content invisible

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

let me first say this : this is not a duplicate of [Bootstrap col-sm making content disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570583/bootstrap-col-sm-making-content-disappear). I have checked to see if I have missed any `rows`, but those are fine.

having said that, I'm using a 24 column bootstrap, and adding any `col-xs` class is making my content invisible. I can see the images and buttons on firebug, but they aren't visible on the scree. disabling `float:left` on the column class makes the content visible again.  I have checked using firefox, chrome and MS Edge, and got the same result. HTML for the block that is affected:

```
    <div class="container">
    <section id="content-promoted">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-24">
                <h2>Originals</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row bg-dark p-tb-sm">
            <!--start looping-->
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-10">
                <div class="block">
                    <img src="{{ asset('bundles/web/images/p-1.png') }}" class="img-responsive">
                    <div class="block-content p-a-sm">
                        <h4 class="name">Name</h4>
                        <p class="artist">Artists</p>
                        <div class="block-meta">
                            <button class="btn btn-clear"><i class="icon-clock"></i> Watch Later</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-clear"><i class="icon-heart"></i> 15,24,000</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-clear"><i class="icon-eye"></i> 99,99,999</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--end looping-->
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-10">
                <div class="block">
                    <img src="{{ asset('bundles/web/images/p-1.png') }}" class="img-responsive">
                    <div class="block-content p-a-sm">
                        <h4 class="name">NAme</h4>
                        <p class="artist">artists</p>
                        <div class="block-meta">
                            <button class="btn btn-clear"><i class="icon-clock"></i> Watch Later</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-clear"><i class="icon-heart"></i> 15,24,000</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-clear"><i class="icon-eye"></i> 99,99,999</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 landscape">
                <div class="block">
                    <img src="{{ asset('bundles/web/images/p-2.jpg') }}" class="img-responsive">
                    <div class="block-content p-lr-sm p-tb-xs">
                        <h4 class="name">name</h4>
                        <p class="artist">artists</p>
                        <div class="block-meta">
                            <button class="btn btn-clear"><i class="icon-clock"></i> Watch Later</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-clear"><i class="icon-heart"></i> 15,24,000</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-clear"><i class="icon-eye"></i> 99,99,999</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="block">
                    <img src="{{ asset('bundles/web/images/p-2.jpg') }}" class="img-responsive">
                    <div class="block-content p-lr-sm p-tb-xs">
                        <h4 class="name">Name</h4>
                        <p class="artist">artists</p>
                        <div class="block-meta">
                            <button class="btn btn-clear"><i class="icon-clock"></i> Watch Later</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-clear"><i class="icon-heart"></i> 15,24,000</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-clear"><i class="icon-eye"></i> 99,99,999</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 landscape">
                <div class="block">
                    <img src="{{ asset('bundles/web/images/p-3.jpg') }}" class="img-responsive">
                    <div class="block-content p-lr-sm">
                        <h4 class="name">name</h4>
                        <p class="artist">artists</p>
                        <div class="block-meta">
                            <button class="btn btn-clear"><i class="icon-clock"></i> Watch Later</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-clear"><i class="icon-heart"></i> 15,24,000</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-clear"><i class="icon-eye"></i> 99,99,999</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="block">
                    <img src="{{ asset('bundles/web/images/p-3.jpg') }}" class="img-responsive">
                    <div class="block-content p-lr-sm">
                        <h4 class="name">name</h4>
                        <p class="artist">artists</p>
                        <div class="block-meta">
                            <button class="btn btn-clear"><i class="icon-clock"></i> Watch Later</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-clear"><i class="icon-heart"></i> 15,24,000</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-clear"><i class="icon-eye"></i> 99,99,999</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="block">
                    <img src="{{ asset('bundles/web/images/p-3.jpg') }}" class="img-responsive">
                    <div class="block-content p-lr-sm">
                        <h4 class="name">name</h4>
                        <p class="artist">artists</p>
                        <div class="block-meta">
                            <button class="btn btn-clear"><i class="icon-clock"></i> Watch Later</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-clear"><i class="icon-heart"></i> 15,24,000</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-clear"><i class="icon-eye"></i> 99,99,999</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="content-carousels">
        <div class="row">
            <!--this is the looped div-->
            <div class="col-sm-24">carousel</div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!--container end-->
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.block{background: black;}
.landscape .block{margin-top: 10px;}
 .landscape .block:first-child{margin-top:0;}
 .block img{border-bottom: 2px solid #00adef; }
 .block-meta{border-top:1px solid #151515;}
  .block .btn-clear{background: none;border:none; margin: 0;padding: 0; border-radius: 0;text-align:left; font-size: 12px;}
```

detailed code is here in this codepen: http://codepen.io/samia92/pen/RRJEmB . resize the window to trigger ``extra-small resolution and the first two block disappears!

Comment: name3 has `col-md-6` class so it's overlaying name1 and most of name2 - either fix it or add `z-index:1` to name1 and name2

Comment: I figured it out. That, plus another div was being created by jquery. Today's my day to mess up simple things!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in your code you don't have any Bootstrap's grid classes on last 2 columns for `xs` screens. So as a result on extra-small screen first two columns are being floated while the rest of two are not floating and overlaying on first two columns.

Your code structure should be like this:

```
<div class="row bg-dark p-tb-sm">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-10"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-10"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 landscape col-xs-10"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 landscape col-xs-10"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make grid of 12 if you don't want to thing messed up

in large view you have

```
col-sm-6 + col-sm-6
```

but in xs view you have `col-xs-10 + col-xs-10` so it is being messed up.

Comment: I have custom configured bootstrap. it is 24 columns, so no, the layout won't be messed up.

Comment: check in case of `xs` or if you configured, that we can say :(